# How to resolve No or missing module errors when converting to an executable using pyinstaller -Python

Tags: qt, pyqt4, anaconda, pyinstaller, pyuic

I am attempting to convert a python file to an executable file. Easy enough right?

I used pyinstaller on a simple program that doesn't import anything. It worked like a charm. Then, I tried it with another dummy program with imported modules, (PyQt4, sys, matplotlib) that my actual program would have. Here I encountered problems.

This error appeared when I ran the application in the 'dist' folder pyinstaller created.

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
>   ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

I found another site with a possible solution to this problem, but his situation wasn't exactly the same: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/118463/

This lead me to trying the QT designer that I downloaded earlier. Perhaps if I could convert the .ui file it produced into a .py file, I would be fine. I could use his solution and all would be well.

That's when I got this error:

> File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 26, in module
>
> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>   mportError: No module named 'PyQt4'

I should also probably mention that all the modules I have are through Anaconda 3

I thought installing pyqt in a conda... project? Would fix the problem. It didn't. To be honest I don't entirely know what those are for.

Now I'm entertaining the idea of just using the c++ files that QT designer makes instead of converting them and importing python to tell the gui what to do.

What do you guys think would solve the errors above?

Comment: I had similar problems using another tool to compile python code. I did not found a proper solution but as a workaround you could try to import the missing module explicitly. E. g. `import encodings`

Comment: That was it. It's hard to believe the solution was that simple.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer so you are able to accept it and other user can find it.

Answer (score 0):

**Short solution / workaround:**
In your python file import the missing module explicitly. In your case: `import encodings`.
**Proper solution:**
By importing every module separately so you might end up imorting many modules and submodules. In this case you need tell pyinstaller where to find the modules (e. g. using compile flags).